# How to mosaic two different land cover together in Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, mosaic

I have two different landcover class first code give me NDVI with 4 class(low-ndvi, moderate-ndvi, high-ndvi, very-high-ndvi) and second code (supervised classification) that is give me 2 class (water and agriculture). I want to combined these two landcover together that at the end give me 6 class (low-ndvi, moderate-ndvi, high-ndvi, very-high-ndvi, water and agriculture) all of them in one image.

```
//Map.addLayer(geometry);
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var point = ee.Geometry.Point(62.6755, 28.097);

 var bangalore = geometry
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
// The following collections were created using the 
// Drawing Tools in the code editor 

 
 
var filtered = s2
//.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-10-01', '2019-11-30'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(bangalore))
  .select('B.*')

var composite = filtered.median().clip(bangalore) 

//////////
var ndvi = composite.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']);
var ndviclass = ee.Image(1)
      .where(ndvi.gt(-1).and(ndvi.lte(0.1)), 1)
      .where(ndvi.gt(0.1).and(ndvi.lte(0.2)), 2)
      .where(ndvi.gt(0.2).and(ndvi.lte(0.3)), 3)
      .where(ndvi.gt(0.3).and(ndvi.lte(1)), 4)
      

// create colors for those classifications
var visparams = {
   "opacity": 1,
    "min": 1,
    "max": 9,
    "palette": ['f7e084','225129', '369b47', '30eb5b' ]
}
var ndviclass1 =ndviclass.clip(geometry)
Map.addLayer(ndviclass1, visparams,'ndvi_class');



// Display the input composite.
var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 3000,
  bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'],
};
//Map.addLayer(composite, rgbVis, 'image');
// be cationion about bands
var bands = ['B4', 'B8'];
//var gcps = urban.merge(bare).merge(water).merge(vegetation)
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection([bareland,urban,water]);
var label = 'landcover';
// Overlay the point on the image to get training data.
var training = composite.sampleRegions({
  collection: polygons,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 30
});

var trained = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train(training, label);

//var classified = image.select(bands).clip(marz).classify(trained);

// Train a classifier.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({
  features: training,  
 classProperty: 'landcover', 
 inputProperties: composite.bandNames()
});
// // Classify the image
 


var classified = composite.classify(classifier);

// Remove the "none_agri" class from the classified image
var nonebarelandMask = classified.select('classification').neq(0);

classified = classified.updateMask(nonebarelandMask);

Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 1, max: 3, palette: [ 'green', 'blue']}, 'classes'); 
 

  
  ///////
var gcp = polygons
var gcp = gcp.randomColumn()
var trainingGcp = gcp.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.6));
var validationGcp = gcp.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', 0.6));
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fe19d44dad0fe43d3a9b16bb78b93da5

Comment: You can use the `ee.Image.addBands()` function to combine all bands into one image.
`var combined=classified.addBands(ndviclass1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can remap `classified` values to the ones you want to use in your final, combined, classification, using `remap()`. Then you combine them with `where()`. The snipped below will keep the NDVI class values and remaps agriculture and water to `5` and `6`.

```
var remappedClassification = classified
  .remap([2, 3], [5, 6])
var combinedClassification = ndviclass
  .where(remappedClassification.gte(5), remappedClassification)
  .clip(geometry)
Map.addLayer(combinedClassification, {min: 1, max: 6, palette: '#129450, #126e45, #1a482f, #122414, #e1cd73, #14439c'}, 'combined')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/94531833305bb508be124e0bb889d8f6